# should i scale the mixed data type before i perform hierarchical clustering?

Tags: r, normalization, hierarchical-clustering

I am working on a Women Entrepreneurship and Labor Force dataset from kaggle. This dataset has categorical and continuous data. I did not scale the data before do the clustering, and i used gower method.But the result is a bit weird.Why i have 2 in the factor data.
This is the dataset.
[image]

The result includes cluster numbers
[image]

Comment: gower measure normalizes continuous variables by their respective ranges.

Comment: @ttnphns does it mean i do not need to scale it beforehand, right? If so, do you happen to know why 2 or 1.46 in the factor variables like level of development? should it be something under 1?