# Should mixed-data (incl. weights) be pre-normalised/scaled/standardised before computation of a distance matrix for hierarchical clustering?

Tags: standardization, hierarchical-clustering, survey-weights, ward, gower-similarity

[should i scale the mixed data type before i perform hierarchical clustering?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503497/should-i-scale-the-mixed-data-type-before-i-perform-hierarchical-clustering)

A question very similar to mine was asked above however it wasn't quite answered...

For background: I am using a large mixed-data survey dataset where I have subsetted to about 8 variables plus a simple weight variable. I am attempting to perform hierarchical clustering in R by first calculating a dissimilarity matrix using Gower's metric, then hierarchical clustering using Ward clustering (from my reading this seems to be suitable given it is sensitive to individual weights).

When I first learnt of hierarchical clustering, it was only with regards to continuous numerical data and data scaling seemed sensible and straightforward. To my understanding from the above question, the Gower metric does perform some sort of scaling, but is there any need for data pre-processing or other normalisation? If not, how should I apply my weights? Is there a need to scale them before applying them during the clustering step?

Up to this point, I have calculated a similarity matrix using all variables minus my weights via `daisy`, then using the `hclust` function with `members = WEIGHT` for the weighting.

First time asking something on StackExchange so I apologise if there are useful details missing. Let me know and I will provide clarification.